# Phonegap \ Cordova 1.6.0 what is going on?

Tags: xcode, cordova

i downloaded the new phonegap actually cordova and now my projects dont have th www folder..what's going on? I used phonegap 0.9 and was way easier why thay are messing around and the documentation is sloppy...

please help, where is the real phonegap??

Comment: I agree to the fact that the documentation is sloppy. It doesn't show examples as in how to work with Cordova. I am also having issues here.

Answer (score 6):

Phonegap's new name is Cordova now(After getting accepted by Apache). So Use Cordova 1.6.0 now and for documentation check this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.0/index.html